# A div has been removed by a js code, but it will stay on the page for a long time in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this page:http://jiazhaokaoshi.com.cn/Jiaxiao/index.php?m=Mnks&a=test
**If I haven't srolled the page, no problem! wonderful,everything is OK!** 
But when I have scrolled the page, for example,go to here:
 http://jiazhaokaoshi.com.cn/Jiaxiao/index.php?m=Mnks&a=test#51
When I use Chrome (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m) to browse this page(**don't forget the anchor`#51`**).
If I click the button ('提交试卷') ,the  page will  pop up a box-div, that's OK.
[image: click the button ('提交试卷')]
But when I click the 'X', in fact, I have removed the background div, but it will stay on the page for a long time.[image: click the 'X'][image]
I need to say ,the `<div id="popbox">...</div>`and the`<div id="popbackground">..</div>` are added.So I use the .live()

```
$(".popclose").live('click',function(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $("#popbox").remove();
        $("#popbackground").remove();
    });
})
```

Sometimes the background div will disappear 2 minutes later.
I have tried to update the jquery to `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`
and update the code:

```
$(document).on('click','.popclose',function(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut(100,function(){
        $("#popbox").remove();
        $("#popbackground").remove();
    });
})
```

It doesn't work too.

Comment: Just a thought - replace `.live` with `.on`. Let me know if that fixes it. `.live` is deprecated.

Comment: @m59 tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/), but it still doesn't work in Chrome.  Works fine in FF.

Comment: @Birrel that's because you didn't include jQuery :) It works fine and your answer isn't the solution.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that I didn't include it - my bad.  Yours solution works.  The answer I provided below works fine too.  Something about skinning cats and more than one way.

Comment: You are confused about the suggestions regarding `live`. Trust me. Change your code to `$(document).on('click', '.popclose', function() {` It does what you want.

Comment: The next issue I suspect is the href property of your `a` tags. You can remove this `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: @m59 I trust you, I have tried,if I use `.on()` instead of `.live()`,the `$('#popbox')` can't fadeOut. Now I delet the `href="javascript:void(0);"`.Let me try again.

Comment: @m59 It doesn't work too. I am sorry.In other browse ,this question doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its unrelated to the code snippets currently posted. I think the root cause is an issue that comes from mixing and matching jquery, pure javascript and html-as-string. Take the below section:

```
box:function(title,content){
    //box样式均在box.css里面
    var popbackground= '<div class="popbackground" id="popbackground"></div>';
    $(popbackground).appendTo(document.body);
    var boxdiv = '<div class="popbox" id="popbox">\
        <div class="innerpopbox">\
            <div class="title">\
                <div id="poptitle"></div>\
                <a class="btn-close popclose" href="javascript:void(0);">×</a>\
            </div>\
            <div class="content" id="popcontent"></div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';

    $(boxdiv).appendTo(document.body);
    //MORE OF YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

and change it to:

```
box:function(title,content){
  var body = $('body'),
  popbackground = $('<div class="popbackground" id="popbackground"/>');

  var boxdiv = $('<div class="popbox" id="popbox"/>')
            .append($('<div class="innerpopbox"/>')
              .append($('<div class="title" />')
                .append($('<a class="btn-close popclose" href="#"/>').text('x'))
                .append($('<div id="poptitle"/>'))
            )
            .append($('<div class="content" id="popcontent" />')));

  popbackground.appendTo(body);
  boxdiv.appendTo(body);
  //MORE OF YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

I'll come and write a bit more soon, but basically what is happening is jquery isn’t aware that what your appending to the body is an html element that may need changing in the future. As far as its concerned its just some string of text that's being appended to the body - which is being interpreted by the browser. But isn't being **fully** interpreted by jQuery. Which means trying to work with it later becomes buggy.

tl;dr: When creating elements using jquery - do them like so:

```
var foo = $('<div />').addClass('bar').attr('id', 'bam');
```

That will ensure that jQuery can interoperate with it properly.

Note: This is [sort of] the same in vanilla javascript, one does not simply:

```
document.body.appendChild('<div id="foo>Heres some text</div>"');
```

One must create the element first, then append it. jQuery - if you want it to work - is the same.

Comment: Weird, that fixed it for me when editing it in chrome dev tools [and just double checked]. I cant see the code live on your site now - has it been uploaded?

Comment: I test in my computer. upload it soon.wait for a moment.

Comment: wonderful!!but when I close the pop-box, the anchor is disappeared.the page go to the top

Comment: I am waiting for you.my problem has been solved,but when I close the pop-box ,the anchor(`#51`) of the url will disapperar.so the page will goto the top.

Comment: This is a different issue, so i wont edit the existing answer. You need to cancel the default action that is triggered when you click an anchor tag [the X]. Add return false to the end of the .popclose event handler. Like so:



`$(".popclose").on('click',function(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut(100,function(){
        $("#popbox").remove();
        $("#popbackground").remove();
    });
    return false;
});`

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/1/)

```
$(".popclose").click(function(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $("#popbox").remove();
        $("#popbackground").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tested in FireFox and Chrome

Comment: Oh,I need to say ,the `<div class="popclose">...</div>` is added.So I use the .live()

Comment: m59 and jonLuci have good solutions using `.on()` instead of `.live()`

Comment: I use `.on()` instead of `.live()` , the box can't be closed.

Comment: So is neither one a solution?  Theirs nor mine?  Not quite sure what you're looking for, these are both solutions that work.

Comment: @Birrel Like I said, the problem isn't the click function at all :)

Comment: Sorry ,my english is too bad. I mean, if I use `.on()` instead of `.live()`,the `$('#popbox')` can't fadeOut.

Comment: @m59 I only know what I've used in the past, so you might be right about it.  I don't know how the standards have changed.  The fiddle I created with his stock code (even including JQuery) didn't work - as described in his post.  Changing the script to either of our solutions works perfectly in Chrome.  Your solution works like he wants, but I'm pretty sure mine does too.  I'm not sure what's wrong with it otherwise.

Comment: @zhoumengkang [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/3/) fiddle is with `.on()` and fades out fine on Chrome.  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/1/) fiddle uses the method I proposed with `.click()` and also fades out fine on Chrome.  I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: @Birrel Have you seen the page? There's nothing ordinary that causes the behavior he's having an issue with. It's some kind of glitch probably caused by really bad js or css code.

Comment: @m59 Ahhh, mhmmm.  You're right. I get you now.  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/4/) fiddle is using the code straight from his site, with the `.live()` and works just fine in Chrome.  I think I got myself turned around with that first fiddle where I forgot to include JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is working fine, instead of slow, you can manually give the fadeOut time. try this:

```
$(".popclose").on('click',function(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut(100,function(){
        $("#popbox").remove();
        $("#popbackground").remove();
    });
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmz4F/3/)

Comment: Oh,I need to say ,the `<div class="popclose">...</div>` is added.So I use the .live()